# How to merge or add rows based on IF condition while maintaining column row order

Tags: indexing, merge, excel-formula, match, rows

I need to merge several sheets and maintain data integrity. I have managed to reduce the problem to the following example and would really appreciate some help.  The two columns have to be merged into one.  The data in a column has to stay in the order it is originally in as each cell is a code that refers to time data.  The duplicates need to be reduced to one entry as the whole data set will later be geo coded and duplicates are not tolerated.

The data is complicated and messy but essentially the problem i cannot solve can be artificially reduced to the following for simplicity:

[edit:  Yellow bus stops at the following stop codes in the given order.
Blue bus stops at the following stop codes in the given order.
The order in which the buses stop cannot be changed.
The output is one list including all of the stop codes only once, retaining the order present in both lists.]

[image: two columns with some common entries]

I want to change it to this:

[image]

The colour coding is just to make it clear to readers here. 
The green represents where duplicates have been reduced to one (this will allow me to vlookup the data against the code and enter the data from both sheets in the same row.

The order that the codes are in must be maintained so i think i just have to move all the data down.

So, this is, (conceptually), what i was trying to do as a first stage.

[image]

Each row retains the order of data but is spread across enough rows to have enough space for both columns in one. The duplicates take the position of the one which has greater row number.

The rest of the solution follows procedurally. I can then delete duplicate codes, and create a new list with all of the values, then remove the spaces.

So if i can get to there i should be ok.

Therefore, as far as i can tell, i need to match with two formulas:

```
    =MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$11,0)
=MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$11,0)
```

but i am not sure if this is actually the direction to take.
It gives me the row numbers on which the common entries occur, but I am not sure how recreate the necessary positions.
Perhaps i need to create these dummy columns and then count the necessary total rows, but how to do that between errors?
Or, have a dynamic running offset.  But not sure how to do that either.  I am finding it very difficult to wrap my head around it.

It has occurred to me that each value will be on the row number equal to the number of unique values in the two columns above it.

Many thanks in advance for any pointers / solution.
I have tried to reduce the problem down and make it as clear as possible.  If anyone can see the solution and can also see where i need to focus my learning, advice on specific area of training would also be welcome.
Cheers
D

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is more easily addressed with VBA. Let's assume you are working in columns A and B (meaning, 1st and 2nd columns). In your example you have two columns and 11 rows, and since you want to handle your data row-by-row, row is the outer loop and column is the inner loop:

```
Sub Indexing()
Dim irow, icol, count As Integer
Dim lookIn, FoundRange As Range
count = 1
For irow = 1 To 11:
    For icol = 1 To 2:
            Cells(irow, icol).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Set lookIn = Range("F1:F" & count)
            Set FoundRange = lookIn.Find(what:=Cells(irow, icol).Value, lookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
                Range("F" & count).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                count = count + 1
            End If
    Next icol
Next irow

End Sub
```

This yields the following result, output in column F:

[image]

Note that the order is slightly different from yours, but it sort of makes more sense. In your result example, you have 113 before 68, although the first number to appear in row #4 is 68. There are other differences so maybe I misunderstood the order you wanted.

You can adapt this code as follows:

- If you have more columns, just replace the 2 in the icol loop by whatever number of columns you want.
- If you have more rows, just replace the 11 in the irow loop by whatever number of rows you want.
- If you want this to be written in a different column (not column F, as it is now), just replace F with the column letter that you want.

If you are not familiar with Macros and need help setting this up, let me know.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, i have been going blind trying to do this with formulas.  I have made an edit as i hadn't expressed it properly.  The order in each column has to be retained as they are chronological events.  Can your code be modified?
Thanks again.

  "[edit: Yellow bus stops at the following stop code in the given order. Blue bus stops at the following stop codes in the given order. The order in which the buses stop cannot be changed. The output is one list including all of the stop codes only once, retaining the order present in both lists.]"

Comment: Hi, I don't see the logic in your order. It looks like sometimes you want the first column first (you start with 501), but others you want blue first (you have 113 ahead of 68). If we read this row-by-row, columnA-to-columnB, 68 should appear ahead of 113. Can you please clarify?

Comment: It doesn't mater if yellow is before blue or blue before yellow. As long as the order that each column is in is maintained. As you can see from the second image with the green. The yellow column has maintained its original order. As has the Blue column. I have a solution to this. I will ask the coder to post it here.